# What answer does the guaranteed answer provide?

Tags: discussion, unicoin

For april 1st and the Unicoin. What answer is guaranteed? I purchased it and I am curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one you choose when you buy your magnificent Unicorn power. You have made a wise investment. Take a look at your questions.

Comment: Was hoping it would show up in this question :)

Comment: @GMNoob Unicorns have no power in the domain of Meta.